# Concrete example of digits recognition using neural network

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, ocr

I am a very (very) beginner with ANN and reading [this tutorial](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt4.html). The author explains ANN on the following OCR example.

There are binary images with a 8x8 grid with equal cells (cells have always same size). Every digit is formed using some cells of the grid. Every image has one of the digits `0-9`.

Besides it is supposed that all trained digits also have equal 8x8 grids (for example vector of trained digit `4` = vector of recognized digit `4`).

For example this is the image of digit `4`:
[image]

So he says that we need 64 inputs (one input for every grid cell). Besides we need 10 output nodes (as we have 10 digits). It is supposed that there is one layer of hidden nodes. But I can't understand how all this works to give result.

Could anyone say how many hidden nodes we need and what must these hidden nodes do?

P.S. We don't need to do here all helping OCR processing - preprocessing, segmentation, presentation. We already have vector of features with length 64.

Answer (score 0):

We can have any number of hidden neurons. The weights are matrices that multiply the input vector, so the output of a layer can be any size. In your example, the weight matrices would have the following sizes. Note: I'm excluding the non-linearity e.g. sigmoid, tanh or relu because they operate element-wise and don't change the shape.

```
output = output_weights * hidden_weights * input
10 x 1    10 x num_hid    num_hid x 64     64 x 1
```

What the hidden neurons actually do is far more subtle. In this application, you're trying to find a decision boundary that separates the space of "64-pixel images that look like a 4" from "64-pixel images that look like a 3" etc. A single layer neural net (aka a perceptron) can only compute a linear decision boundary. A deeper neural net gives it more flexibility to model more complicated decision boundaries.

For a better intuition, try playing around with the [Tensorflow web demo](http://playground.tensorflow.org/). You can vary the parameters and see how adding more layers adds more expressiveness, and how adding more neurons changes the accuracy.